# how to add array of particular schema type in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mern

i want to add that question schema as the type inside that questions array in topicSchema, but cant do that as it gives error. How can i add array of particular schema type. Is there a way?

```
const question_schema = require('./Question')

const topicSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: [...Object.values(topics_enum)]
    },
    icon: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    questions: [question_schema]
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("topics", topicSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, use type and ref,
you need to use this formatting in order to reference the schema itself:

```
questions: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'question_schema'
    }
],
```

The type `(Schema.Types.ObjectId)` will add the object id for each question in the array (which you can then iterate over later to find each question by those IDs), and the ref `('question_schema')` allows `mongoose` to figure out which of your schemas it should be referencing. As long as the ref is the same as your variable name, it should connect using ref.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state the type of the object as an array, try:

```
questions:{
   type: [question_schema],
}
```